# Difference between .val and normal string javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If I have an input

```
<input id="one" type="text"/>
```

and inside that input I put the following

```
{"DateTimeStamp" : "\/Date(123108128123)\/"}
```

What is the difference between calling

```
$("#one").val() //results in  {"DateTimeStamp" : "\/Date(123108128123)\/"}
var x =  '{"DateTimeStamp" : "\/Date(123108128123)\/"}' //results in  {"DateTimeStamp" : "/Date(123108128123)/"}
```

Why does the var x string strip out the backslashes?

Comment: Backlash is an escape character. Like in most languages. So you can do \n to go to the new line for example. That's why it's striped. If you want to print '\' you should put in '\\'.

Comment: Because they are escaping the forward slashes

Comment: `\`` is the escape character in JavaScript. If you are assigning a value, you need to use `\\ `

Answer (score 3):

Because,
When you declare string x "\" is  considered as an escaped character will be used when you want to include special characters as  a part of your string.
While when you enter any text in input box what ever you are entreating will be considered (including special characters), special characters will not required to be handled separately.